# GitLab Artifact with no subfolders

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create an artifacts file using GitLab pipeline that will contain all the files without any subfolders.

I tried the following

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r * .public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

But the result is I get public folder in the artifacts zip. But unless I have a folder in the root directory there is nothing I can refer to in the artifacts paths.

Comment: `artifacts.path` in your Gitlab CI file will define _exactly_ the files that will be zipped. If you specify `public`, then this whole directory _only_ will be put in your artifacts archive. What do you hope to achieve here ? The root directory is the one where the job has been created.

Comment: Thanks - your comment pointed me in the right direction. Simply using root folder in paths resolved my issue.